# Can I bypass the lock screen on my Samsung Galaxy S22 without factory reset?

Tags: samsung, locked-out

My phone usually asks for my thumbprint, yesterday it wouldn't let me use it and asked for the pin. When I entered the pin it said incorrect. I tried so many times that the lock screen time out is now up to 24 hours. I didn't know you had to turn on the unlock phone remotely, I thought it was automatic so now I can't unlock it via my samsung account. Is there any way to bypass the pin code screen without wiping my phone?

Comment: I don't think so. Passwords are there so no one except you can unlock it. If you can plug it into the PC and enable mtp from notifications (which you can't on new Android versions. What's yours?) That's your best bet. Else you'll have to format it. I have heard of local people who unlock phones without deleting data (old models). Not sure how. Enlighten me

Comment: Android phones usually ask for PIN at least once a week. And you always have to entre the PIN after a reboot as it is required to file decrypting. May be the phone crashed and rebooted. The PIN exists to protect the phone from unauthorized access. If a backdoor exists everybody who has your phone (e.g, lost or stolen) could access your files...